# Rotate UIView and make it change view size to accomodate it's space relative to rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

The subject of view rotation has been asked, proper manipulation and usage of rotated views havent been adresses properly.

When rotating a view using something in the form of: `view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 deg) // rotate to vertical`

The view content still being drawen according to the original width/height.

For example, given a wrapper view of height 1000px and width of 200px and a `UILabel` inside it, if you would rotate the `UILabel` it's width would still be 200px even though it can span the entire height of it's container, 1000px.

In other words, how can one take a `UILabel` rotate it 90 degrees and make it's width be the height of the entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

Achieving the desired size is a one-liner: I simply gave the label a width constraint equal to the height of its superview. Thus, when the label is rotated, its width is displayed vertically and matches the height of the red superview.

Comment: you're right, had an overlapping constraint issue that disrupted the normal behaviour, thanks!